# JMeter WebDriver Sampler Error for Java

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

By default, jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler has javascript as a Script Language.
As soon as I switch to java, I get this error message.

> ReferenceError: "ImportPackage" is not defined in  at line
>   number 2.

I use JMeter 3.2 and Java 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the WebDriver Sampler plugin, you can report it via [JMeter Plugins support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins). For the time being there is no fix so currently you have the following options:

1. Ignore. This message can be annoying however it isn't critical and you can continue working.
2. Switch to JavaScript language
3. Downgrade to [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) and JDK 7 as [Rhino JavaScript Engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) used in JDK 6 and 7 has this `ImportPackage` function while [Nashorn JavaScript Engine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) which comes with JDK8 doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. I chose the option 3.

Answer (score 1):

With nashorn, importPackage is not defined by default. But, you can eval the following line to get few Rhino compatibility features:

```
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
```

See also: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide

Comment: Thanks, A. Sundararajan. Where should I put that load() statement? At the beginning of the WebDriver Sampler?

Comment: Yes, either at the top of the script using importPackage call - or even a separate engine.eval call before evaluating that WebDriver Sampler script.